# Помогите с питоном, не работает if else

Tags: python

В питоне не работает конструкция if else, подскажите пожалуйста

```
colors = ["синий", "зеленый", "желтый"]
x = input("Угадайте цвет:")
while x in colors:
  if x in colors:
    print("Поздравляем, вы угадали!")
    break
  else:
    x = input("Неправильно, попробуйте еще:")
```

Comment: `while x not in colors:` или `while True` :)

Comment: или можно сделать проще
```while x not in colors:
    x = input("Неправильно, попробуйте еще:")
print("Поздравляем, вы угадали!")
```

Answer (score 2):

Эта конструкция в питоне, конечно, работает. А ошиблись вы в логике, написав условие `while`. Вероятно, должно быть `while True:`

Answer (score 1):

Пиши бесконечный цикл `while True`, то есть:

```
while True:
    if x in colors:
        print("Угадали!")
    else:
        print("Не угадали, пробуйте ещё")
        x=input()
```

Comment: [Справка по markdown (в том числе по оформлению блоков кода)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Answer (score -7):

Разумѣется, ошибка въ Python! Языкъ существуетъ болѣе тридцати лѣтъ, и всё это время никто не замѣчалъ ошибки въ одной изъ базовыхъ конструкцій языка. Какъ хорошо, что нашёлся человѣкъ, который открылъ нам всѣмъ глаза! Опозоренный Гвидо ванъ Россумъ тихо плачетъ въ углу. Крупныя, как крыжовникъ, слёзы скатываются въ его сѣдую бороду.

Кстати, а зачѣмъ здѣсь вообще if-else? Я бы обошёлся безъ else, и даже безъ if.

```
c = "синій зелёный жёлтый".split()
s = "Угадайте цвѣтъ: "
while input(s) not in c:
    s = "Неправильно, попробуйте ещё: "
print("Поздравляемъ, Вы угадали!")
```

На будущее очень рекомендую прочитать эту статью — https://97-things-every-x-should-know.gitbooks.io/97-things-every-programmer-should-know/content/ru/thing_61/

Comment: может быть, начнешь писать на нормальном русском языке

Comment: Нормальный — это со строчной буквы и безъ точки въ концѣ? Нѣтъ, благодарю покорно, кушайте сами.

Comment: вот только дурачка не надо включать

Comment: Стиль письма у вас прикольный, но на этом сайте есть определённые правила. В своём стиле пишите в своих соцсетях или на своём сайте, тут вас будут минусовать, в итоге вы просто не сможете тут ничего писать.

Comment: @CrazyElf, что интересно, я уже спрашивал у данного представителя белоэмигрантских кругов:-) о причине использования дореформенной орфографии, и жаловался,  что читать неудобно. Ответа не было. Но формально правила сайта не нарушены - это русский язык. Минусовать особо не за что при этом. Мне такое не нравится, но и безграмотность в современной орфографии - тоже. А за неё тоже не минусуют.

Comment: Автору же невежливого ответа рекомендую почитать об основной проблеме ИИ - неспособности понимать контекст. Очевидно, что автор не имел в виду неработоспособность конструкции в языке вообще, а лишь в своем примере. Учитывая, что автор почти наверняка школьник, ему это отчасти простительно, а вот взрослому, кто начинает в ответ издеваться над школьником, - не очень.

Comment: @Сергей это не русский язык. Это безграмотное эпигонство.

Comment: @Сергей Русский язык - это всё-таки современный русский, а то эдак и старославянский можно русским назвать и "олбанский" какой-нибудь. За неуважение, в том числе за агрессивную безграмотность, тут очень даже минусуют.